# Problem with polynomial divisilibity proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

> Show that for any natural $k$, $m$, $n$ polynomial $x^{3k}+x^{3m+1}+x^{3m+2}$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$.

My observation:

$$x^a=(x^{a-2}-x^{a-3})(x^2+x+1)+x^{a-3}$$

so,

$$x^{3k}+x^{3m+1}+x^{3m+2}=(x^{3k-2}-x^{3k-3})(x^2+x+1)+x^{3k-3}+(x^{3m-1}-x^{3m-2})(x^2+x+1)+x^{3m-2}+(x^{3n}-x^{3n-1})(x^2+x+1)+x^{3n-1}$$

We can factor $x^2+x+1$, but i don't see any conclusion after that.

Comment: Hi! probably there is a $n$ in the last monomial of your question. 
Try this: $x^2+x+1$ divide your polynomial $p(x)$ if and only if all the roots of $x^2+x+1$ are roots of $p(x)$. Now the roots of $x^2+x+1$ are really nice when you power them to $3$

Comment: Did you try to perform euclidean division with particular values for $k, m$? eg with $k = m = 1$, you get the polynomial $x^3 + x^4 + x^5$, which is $(x^2 + x + 1) \cdot x^3$. Try some values for $k, m$ and try to find a pattern.

Comment: @Menezio Beautifull idea! Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @OlivierRoche Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $q(x)=x^2+x+1$ divides $p(x)=x^{3k}+x^{3m+1}+x^{3n+2}$ if and only if the roots of $q(x)$ are roots of $p(x)$.

Since $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, the roots of $q(x)$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and they are the primitive cubic roots of unity and obviously the following holds:
\begin{gather}
\alpha^3 = \beta^3 =1\\
\alpha^2+\alpha+1 = \beta^2+\beta+1=0
\end{gather}

Now we simply have:
$$
p(\alpha)=\alpha^{3k}+\alpha^{3m+1}+\alpha^{3n+2} = (\alpha^{3})^k+\alpha(\alpha^{3})^m+\alpha^2(\alpha^{3})^n =1+ \alpha+ \alpha^2 =0
$$
and the same thing happens to $\beta$. So $p(\alpha)=p(\beta)=0$ and $x^2+x+1\ | \ p(x)$ for all $n,m,k$

Comment: Or, you can compute the roots of $x^2 + x + 1$ : $e^{\pm i \frac{\pi}{3}}$ and indeed their cube is $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that one way is to show that the roots of $x^2+x+1$ satisfy $x^{3k}+x^{3m+1}+x^{3n+2}=0$, as suggested in comments. Here is an easy approach without using complex numbers:

$$x^{3k}+x^{3m+1}+x^{3n+2}=x^{3k}-1+x(x^{3m}-1)+x^2(x^{3n}-1)+x^2+x+1$$
Now note that $$x^2+x+1\bigg|x^3-1\bigg|x^{3a}-1\ \ \forall a\in\Bbb N$$
Therefore, RHS of the first equation is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ and we are done.